# Could not calculate build plan with SpringSource Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I'm having some troubles with IDE configurations. I can't update my maven project.

```
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\dolgopolov.a\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\dolgopolov.a\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

at `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

Marker is locating near `xml version` and `xmlns`. It says:

```
The word 'xml' is not correctly spelled
The word 'xmlns' is not correctly spelled
```

What's wrong with sts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: The markers you see are just your IDEs spell checker. It doesn't know those two words but they are right in your pom. You can ignore it.

As for you actual problem: Your downloaded dependency might be corrupt in some way. Try deleting the folder `C:\Users\dolgopolov.a\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin` and try to build again. Maven should re-dowload the dependency, hopefully correctly this time.

If this doesn't work you might be behind a proxy and cannot download depencies from the Maven repository correctly at all.